# Batch choice with wrong answer

Tags: batch-file

i want to create a choice programm with batch, where the user gets asked something like this:

```
@echo off

:choice
set /P c=What is 2+2
if /I "%c%" EQU "4" goto :yes
if /I "%c%" EQU "WHAT DO I TYPE IN HERE?" goto :no



:yes
msg * well done
pause
exit
:no
exit
```

So that when you give a wrong answer you will be redirected to :no

Comment: Have you tried just "goto :no" without the if before it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
:choice
set /P c=What is 2+2
if /I "%c%" EQU "4" (goto :yes) else (goto :no)

:yes
msg * well done
pause
exit
:no
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

While foxidrive's answer is optimal for the example you gave, if you are seeking the `compare-op` for not equal to, it is:

```
if "%c%" NEQ "4" Echo Wrong...
```

The other compare op's include:

```
where compare-op may be one of:

    EQU - equal
    NEQ - not equal
    LSS - less than
    LEQ - less than or equal
    GTR - greater than
    GEQ - greater than or equal
```

Quoted from `if /?`.

You can also use:

```
if NOT "%c%"=="4" Echo Wrong...
```

to do this without compare-op's

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i see that i made the wrong question, what i really want to do is to create an activation system with batch.
So, when i insert the right code, it should extract and password protected .rar or an sfx(.exe) file.
This is why i needed it, and this is what i currently really have:

```
 @echo off

:choice
set /P c=Insert Key
if /I "%c%" EQU "123" goto :yes 
if /I "%c%" EQU "321" goto :yes 
if /I "%c%" EQU "132" goto :yes 


:yes
msg * well done
unrar x -p"password" "filename.rar"
pause
exit
:no

exit
```

But it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Thread continues here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724633/batch-licensing-system